# How to generate dropdownlist at runtime based on user Input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to generate dropdownlists based on the count entered by user.Suppose if the user enters 3, then 3 dropdownlists should be generated.
Here is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Make", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Make", ViewBag.Make as SelectList, "Select",  new { @id = "ddlSelect",onchange ="GetOption();"})
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Count", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("Count","", new { @id = "textCount",onblur ="GetCount();"})
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Make, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Make, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Make, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" id="click" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

first of all i am asking the user two select a value from dropdownlist..after that i am asking hime to enter the count..based on that count, i want to generate dropdownlists & want to populate them using viewbag data.

My Model Class is

```
public partial class Cables_List
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Dlink { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Molex { get; set; }
}
```

& Here is my Controller

```
public class BOMController : Controller
{
    private InventoryContext db = new InventoryContext();

    // GET: BOM
    public ActionResult Cables()
    {
        ViewBag.Make = new SelectList(db.Make, "ID", "Name");
        ViewBag.Dlink = new SelectList(db.Cables_List, "Dlink", "Category");
        ViewBag.Molex = new SelectList(db.Cables_List,"Molex","Category")
        return View();
    }
```

I just want to load data from Viewbag.Dlink & Viewbag.Molex . based on user selection from dropdownlist. I am using Database first Approach. Is there any way to achieve this in MVC or i have to use jquery.Kindly guide.

Comment: You can make an ajax call to the server and retrieve the data after the user entered the amount. The result should be an `PartialView` and can be appended to the current view.

Comment: @Cristian thanks for your guidence but I am not so familiar with ajax, is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Cable model:

```
public class Cable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal? Dlink { get; set; }
    public decimal? Molex { get; set; }
}
```

Your ViewModel:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public List<Cable> Cables { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetCables(int Amount)
{
    var model = new HomeViewModel();
    model.Cables = db.Cables_List.ToList();

    return PartialView("_Cable.cshtml", model);
}
```

`_Cable.cshtml` partial view:

```
@model HomeViewModel

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Amount; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("DDname", new SelectList(Model.Cables, "ID", "Category"))
}
```

jQuery call:

```
$(this).on('blur', '#textCount', function () {
    var amount = $(this).val(); // get the inputed number (maybe check if is grater than 0)

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetCables',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { Amount: amount },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#CableWrapper')
                .empty()
                .append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And into your main view put the div where you want the dropdowns to be appended:

```
<div id="CableWrapper"></div>
```